# Как перемножить объекты между собой?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

При заполнении пользователем информации о товаре, объект получается вот такого вида:

```
SendData: {
    Description: 'Крутые кроссовки Nike Air',
    Name: 'Кроссовки Nike',
    Options: {
        Colors: [ 
            {
                Name: 'Красный',
                Alias: '01'
            },
            {
                Name: 'Синий'
                Alias: '02'
            }
        ],
        Sizes: [
            {
                Name: '36',
                Alias: '01'
            },
            {
                Name: '37'
                Alias: '02'
            }
        ],
    },
    Price: 5000,
    VendorCode: 'Nike'
}
```

Опций кроме Colors и Size может быть еще, и данных в массивах Colors и Size больше. Как при всем этом при заполнении всех полей получать подобный массив объектов

```
[
    {
        VendorCode: 'Nike-01-01',
        Color: 'Красный',
        Size: '36',
    },
    ... и так далее, пока не переберутся все возможные комбинации
]
```

Как это реализовать на JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если адаптировать решение из [Как преобразовать данные объекта в другой объект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245355/) , то у меня получается такой код:

```js
const data = {
  SendData: {
      Description: 'Крутые кроссовки Nike Air',
      Name: 'Кроссовки Nike',
      Options: {
          Colors: [
              {
                  Name: 'Красный',
                  Alias: '01'
              },
              {
                  Name: 'Синий',
                  Alias: '02'
              }
          ],
          Sizes: [
              {
                  Name: '36',
                  Alias: '01'
              },
              {
                  Name: '37',
                  Alias: '02'
              }
          ],
      },
      Price: 5000,
      VendorCode: 'Nike'
  },
};

const optionKeys = Object.keys(data.SendData.Options);
const optionValues = Object.values(data.SendData.Options);

const optionAliasSets = getCartesianProduct(
  optionValues.map(options => options.map(({ Alias }) => Alias))
);
const optionNameSets = getCartesianProduct(
  optionValues.map(options => options.map(({ Name }) => Name))
);

const variants = optionAliasSets.map(
  (set, index) => Object.fromEntries([
    ['VendorCode', `${data.SendData.VendorCode}-${set.join('-')}`],
    ...optionKeys.map((name, i) => [name, optionNameSets[index][i]]),
  ])
);

console.log(variants);

function getCartesianProduct(sets) {
  const result = [];

  function cartesianProduct(sets, index, current) {
    if (index === sets.length) {
      result.push(current.slice());
      return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < sets[index].length; i++) {
      current[index] = sets[index][i];
      cartesianProduct(sets, index + 1, current);
    }
  }

  cartesianProduct(sets, 0, []);
  return result;
}
```